# DataBinding, refresh data if DataContext changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My code:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTut.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int index = 0;
    public Customer Tmp;
    List<Customer> ar = new List<Customer>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ar.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "qwe", LastName = "rty" });
        ar.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "asd", LastName = "asd" });
        this.Tmp = ar[index];
        this.DataContext = this.Tmp;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tmp = ar[++index];
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Tmp"));
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

So when application loads, everything is fine - textbox shows "qwe", but button, which should load second customer object doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not changing the `DataContext`.  You're changing the value in the property that you set the `DataContext` to.

You don't need a `Tmp` property at all.  Just change the `DataContext` in your event handler, e.g.:

```
DataContext = ar[++index];
```

Comment: Yes, it works then.. But what's INotifyPropertyChanged for then? Tmp is property, and I change it, so it should update UI, right?

Comment: @bah - No, nothing you have is "bound to" Tmp, so changing it would not affect the UI. When do you do `this.DataContext = this.Tmp` that sets DataContext to the same reference as Tmp (which is `qwe`). So changing Tmp won't affect the DataContext.

Comment: Ah well, this will do for now, it seems there are a lot of things for me to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make Tmp a property and then bind DataContext to it, like this;

```
private Customer tmp;    
public Customer Tmp {
    get {
        return this.tmp;
    }
    set {
        this.tmp = value;
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Tmp"));
    }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ar.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "qwe", LastName = "rty" });
    ar.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "asd", LastName = "asd" });
    this.Tmp = ar[index];
    this.SetBinding(DataContextProperty, new Binding("Tmp") { Source = this });
}
```

Comment: But.. but.. Why is it done like that? If property can hold value itself why do this?

Comment: @bah - You only set DataContext once, so it would never update. By binding it to your Tmp property, then anytime you change Tmp the DataContext will also change.